# Is there a GUI possibility to find removed files in GIT?

Tags: git, github

I have a code in git, that finds some specified deleted files:

```
cd locationofrepo 
git log --all --stat --diff-filter=D --oneline -- "*whatIwanttofind*"
```

And the result is quite exactly what I need. However, I need to open git CMD, find which commit the deleted file was in. Then open GitHub Desktop, find the commit somewhere in the history, and then I can view the deleted file. I know I can use another git command to find the exact file and write it to a text file, but I am looking for a more user-friendly solution for non-programmers.

Is there any way to use a GUI or web interface to search for deleted files? Azure DevOps Repos does not support searching for deleted files (or I didn't find it), GitHub Desktop does not support searching for deleted files (or I didn't find it), but I cannot believe there is no software solution for this easy question. Is there any non-comment line solution to find deleted files?

Comment: Don't know of any GUIs for this, but can't you build the github URL to the deleted file once you get the path and commit? You could have a script do your query and build the URL, then you can print and copy it manually, or tell the browser to open the URL from the script itself so no-technical users can just execute the script without opening a terminal.